# Permission denied when trying to run app engine project locally

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

The OS MacOS X. Using the terminal, I tried following the steps of how to run a GAE application in a local data store.  I dragged the file dev_appserver.sh, located in bin folder afterwards, dragged the war folder of my GAE project.

I get this error "Permission Denied" when I run it from the terminal.

> /Eclipse-EE/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.15/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.15/bin/dev_appserver.sh
>   -deploy /Users/myUserName/Documents/workspace/project-name/GAE/war

What could be the problem

Comment: try sudo.. most likely your or someone else installed with admin privileges.

Comment: I added the sudo but now it says command not found, are there arguments I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Permission u+x to the appcfg.sh file

Note: If you are using Mac OS X or Linux, you must give the command files executable permission before you can run them. For example, to give appcfg.sh executable permission, enter the following command from the appengine-java-sdk/bin/ directory: chmod u+x appcfg.sh

Reference link - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse